# When I am running this query from back end, getting error

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, backend

```
SQL> select
  2  DECODE (TNOT_NOTICE_TYPE,
  3      '1200', 'Duration Challenge ',
  4      '1400', 'Informal Overrun Warning ',
  5      '1500', 'Works Comments ',
  6      '1600', 'Direction on Timing ',
  7      '1601', 'Direction on Placing Apparatus ',
  8      '1602', 'Undue Delay ',
  9      '1611', 'Grant Permit ',
 10      '1613', 'Refuse Permit ',
 11      '2100', 'FPN Notice ',
 12      '2101', 'FPN Withdrawal ',
 13      '2200', 'FPN Comments ',
 14      '2600', 'Inspection ',
 15      '2800', 'Temporary Traffic Signal Application Responses '
 16      ) || 'Received' AS "Subject",
 17  DECODE (TNOT_NOTICE_TYPE,
 18      '1200', 'Duration Challenge - ',
 19      '1400', 'Informal Overrun Warning - ',
 20      '1500', 'Works Comments - ',
 21      '1600', 'Direction on Timing - ',
 22      '1601', 'Direction on Placing Apparatus - ',
 23      '1602', 'Undue Delay - ',
 24      '1611', 'Grant Permit - ',
 25      '1613', 'Refuse Permit - ',
 26      '2100', 'FPN Notice - ',
 27      '2101', 'FPN Withdrawal - ',
 28      '2200', 'FPN Comments - ',
 29      '2600', 'Inspection - ',
 30      '2800', 'Temporary Traffic Signal Application Responses - '
 31      ) || SUBSTR(TNOT_WORKS_REF, 3, 3) AS "Alert Description",
 32  SUBSTR(TNOT_WORKS_REF, 3, 3) AS "District"    ,
 33  TNOT_SENDER_ORG_REF as "Org Ref",
 34  TNOT_SENDER_DIST_REF as "Dist Ref",
 35  TNOT_DATE_MODIFIED as "Date Modified",
 36  TNOT_DATE_MODIFIED as "Date Modified",
 37  TNOT_WORKS_REF as "Works Ref",
 38  TNOT_COMMENTS as "Comments",
 39  TNOT_WORKS_DESCRIPTION AS "Works Description",
 40  TNOT_LOC_DESCRIPTION AS "Location Description",
 41  TNOT_NOTICE_TYPE ,
 42  TNOT_CREATED_DATIM
 43  from TMA_NOTICES
 44  where
 45  TNOT_SENT_RECEIVED = 'R'
 46  AND TNOT_WORKS_REF LIKE 'AY009%'
 47  AND TNOT_NOTICE_TYPE IN ('1200','1400', '1500', '1600', '1601', '1602', '16
11', '1613', '2100', '2101', '2200','2600', '2800')
 48  AND TNOT_CREATED_DATIM BETWEEN '01-OCT-19 00:00:00' and SYSDATE
 49  ORDER BY TNOT_NOTICE_TYPE, TNOT_CREATED_DATIM DESC;
AND TNOT_CREATED_DATIM BETWEEN '01-OCT-19 00:00:00' and SYSDATE
                               *
```

> ****ERROR at line 48:
>
> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string****

SQL>

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue when your input string `'01-OCT-19 00:00:00'` is converted to a date. By default, It uses `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of your session to convert the string to date and if provided string and `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` do not match then this error is thrown.

So better is to convert the string to date using `TO_DATE` function or `DATE` literal as follows:

```
Replace '01-OCT-19 00:00:00' with -> DATE '2019-10-01'
-- OR --
Replace '01-OCT-19 00:00:00' with -> TO_DATE('01-OCT-19 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

> AND TNOT_CREATED_DATIM BETWEEN '01-OCT-19 00:00:00' and SYSDATE

`'01-OCT-19 00:00:00'` is a **STRING** literal and not a **DATE**. You must always explicitly convert it to DATE data type when comparing with dates. I would prefer the **ANSI date literal** in your case:

```
AND TNOT_CREATED_DATIM BETWEEN DATE '2019-10-01' and SYSDATE
```

The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified in exactly this format `('YYYY-MM-DD')`. If you have a time portion, then use `TO_DATE`:

```
TO_DATE('01-OCT-19 00:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```

The default date format for an Oracle DATE value is specified by the initialization parameter **NLS_DATE_FORMAT**.